# How to make a *particular* section of a footnote left justified?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, url

I have read a lot about making footnotes left justified **in general**, but I have not found anything that would allow me to left justify only **particular** sections of a footnote.

Fox example, I would like my footnote to look like this:

```
1 This is justified text.  Note that there  is an indent  at the beginning  of the footnote
  which prevents  the  second  line  from  continuing  below  the  footnote number. The new
  paragraph contains a link and should look like this:
  Source: http://www.example.com/this-is-a-very-long-link-whichs-words-are-separated-by-
  hyphens-note-that-the-second-paragraph-contains-the-link-and-should-be-left-justified-
  like-this
```

Comment: use `this:\\ Source : \url{http://....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a new paragraph and set the paragraph using `\raggedright`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % If you're using hyperref

\begin{document}

First\footnote{This is justified text.  Note that there  is an indent  at the beginning  of the footnote
  which prevents  the  second  line  from  continuing  below  the  footnote number. 
  This is justified text.  Note that there  is an indent  at the beginning  of the footnote
  which prevents  the  second  line  from  continuing  below  the  footnote number.}
Second\footnote{This is justified text.  Note that there  is an indent  at the beginning  of the footnote
  which prevents  the  second  line  from  continuing  below  the  footnote number. The new
  paragraph contains a link and should look like this:

  \raggedright
  Source: \url{http://www.example.com/this-is-a-very-long-link-which-words-are-separated-by-hyphens-note-that-the-second-paragraph-contains-the-link-and-should-be-left-justified-like-this}}
Third\footnote{This is justified text.  Note that there  is an indent  at the beginning  of the footnote
  which prevents  the  second  line  from  continuing  below  the  footnote number. 
  This is justified text.  Note that there  is an indent  at the beginning  of the footnote
  which prevents  the  second  line  from  continuing  below  the  footnote number.}

\end{document}
```

Using [`url`](//ctan.org/pkg/url) allows for proper alignment and formatting of the URL. This works with [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) also.

Comment: I am using `hyperref`. But when I write `\footnote{\raggedright\textbf{See:} \url{http://www.example.com/very-very-very-long-link-so-long-that-it-should-continue-on-the-next-line}}}` and I will get something like `See: http:` in the first line and the rest `//www.example.com/very-very-very-long-link-so-long-that-it-should-continue-to-the-next-line` in the second line.

Comment: @Nemgathos: Add `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` before loading [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/nBHvgdFE) (and [the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbxm2.png)).